# How to do replication in ChronicleQueue 5

Tags: java-11, chronicle-queue

I am migrating from jdk8 to jdk11 and hence trying to use chronicle-queue v5.

In ChroincleQueue version 3 we had dedicated methods for creating SourceQueue and SinkQueue.
But I am finding it little difficult to implement the same with ChronicleQueue v5.

I am trying to follow [this](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/blob/ea/docs/replication.adoc). In the doc they have mentioned use of `ReplicatedQueue` and `ReplicatedQueueCfg` classes. I looked into different classes of all the other [packages](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/net.openhft) of Chronicle but didn't find any of these classes.

How can I implement replication using ChronicleQueue5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Replication is a commercial extension for Chronicle 4+

https://chronicle.software/queue-enterprise/